# Unexpected break in nested loop doesn't show up in debugger

Tags: javascript, loops, nested-loops

The purpose of the code is to build a series of nested HTML  using information in objects:

Here are the informational objects I created:

```
function branch(level,sciname,comname,parent,children){
    this.level = level;
    this.sciname = sciname;
    this.comname = comname;
    this.parent = parent;
    this.children = children;}

var animalia = new branch(1,'Animalia','Animals',"",['chordata']);
var chordata = new branch(2,'Chordata','Chordates',animalia,['petromyzontida','actinopterygii']);
var actinopterygii = new branch(3,'Actinopterygii','Ray-finned Fishes',chordata,['siluriformes','scorpaeniformes','salmoniformes','percopsiformes','perciformes','osteoglossiformes','osmeriformes','lepisosteiformes','gasterosteiformes','gadiformes','esociformes','cyprinodontiformes','cypriniformes','clupeiformes','atheriniformes','anguilliformes','amiiformes','acipenseriformes']);
var petromyzontida = new branch(3,'Petromyzontida','Lampreys',chordata,['petromyzontiformes']);
```

And here is the script:

```
    function CreateDiv(parent,child,z,width,height,top,left,bgcolor){
        var parent_ = document.getElementById(parent);
        var newdiv = document.createElement("div"); 
        newdiv.setAttribute("id",child);
        newdiv.style.zIndex = z;
        newdiv.style.position = "absolute";
        newdiv.style.width = width + "%";
        newdiv.style.height = height + "%";
        newdiv.style.top = top + "%";
        newdiv.style.left = left + "%";
        newdiv.style.backgroundColor = bgcolor;
        parent_.appendChild(newdiv);}

function CreateTree(){
    var firstdiv = document.createElement("div");
    firstdiv.setAttribute("id","animalia");
    document.getElementById("container1").appendChild(firstdiv);
    var parent1 = "animalia";
    var children1 = window[parent1].children;
    var numbchildren1 = children1.length;
    var rowcounter1 = 1;
    var columncounter1 = 0;
    for (i=0;i<numbchildren1;i++){
        var child1 = children1[i];
        var z1 = 2;
        var columns1 = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(numbchildren1));
        var width1 = (100/columns1) - 2;
        var rows1 = Math.ceil(numbchildren1/columns1);
        var height1 = (100/rows1) - 2;
        var top1 = rowcounter1*height1 - height1 + 1;
        var left1 = columncounter1*width1 + 1;                          
        var bgcolor1 = "#B43333";   
        CreateDiv(parent1,child1,z1,width1,height1,top1,left1,bgcolor1);
        var numbchildren2 = window[child1].length;
        if ((i/rowcounter1) == columns1){
            rowcounter1 = rowcounter1 + 1;}
            else {rowcounter1 = rowcounter1;}
        if (columncounter1 == columns1){
            columncounter1 = 1;}
            else {columncounter1 = columncounter1 + 1;}
        var rowcounter2 = 1;
        var columncounter2 = 0;
        console.log("before:" + columncounter2);
        for (j=0;j<numbchildren2;j++){          
            console.log("after:" + columncounter2);
            var child2 = children2[j];
            var z2 = 3;
            var columns2 = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(numbchildren2));
            var width2 = (100/columns2) - 1;
            var rows2 = Math.ceil(numbchildren2/columns2);
            var height2 = (100/rows2) - 1;
            var top2 = rowcounter2*height2 - height2 + 1;
            var left2 = columncounter2*width2 - width2 + 1;                         
            var bgcolor2 = "#B48233";   
            CreateDiv(parent2,child2,z2,width2,height2,top2,left2,bgcolor2);}}}
```

I've run the code through a debugger dozens of times and I get no errors.  Yet the script does not fully execute.  I suspected an infinite loop but I fail to see why that would occur and after going over the code in great detail, I can find no real problems.  I can tell where the code seems to break.  There are two console.log() statements in the above code.  The first console statement gets properly logged, but the second one does not.  The debugger shows no errors (Firebug), but the code still fails to fully execute.  Please help!  And suggestions or criticism will be very welcome as I'm still learning some of the basics.

As a note: Eventually, I will add to this process to create several layers of nested  elements, but wanted to get just the first couple layers right before I begin nesting things further as once I do that additional nesting should be relatively easy.

Comment: Why are your contructor functions lowercase and your normal functions Uppercase? This is so confusing!

Comment: Just a guess but I'm going to say that `numbchildren2` is zero or undefined at the start of your loop.

Comment: Also, having groups be global variables (and doing `window[childrenname]`) is dangerous, since global variables are prone to being overwritten. While it is true that biological nomenclature is not that likely to name clash with builtin stuff, you should still put all the branches inside a separate `var branches` object.

Comment: I'll look into these things.  I'm green on this stuff and have zero previous programming experience, so I just have to keep at it.

Comment: The thing that is really screwing me up, is errors not showing up in the debugger.  I have come to heavily depend on it to show me mistakes and when it doesn't, I'm lost.

Comment: @WyoBuckeye: Don't worry, my fist program was also for systematics, and it was a complete mess too :) As for the debugger, have you figured out how to use breakpoints and step-by-step instruction stepping? I find that as I get used to the debugger I use console.log less and less. In particular, I really like to using the console to inspect variables and expressions and being able to move up and down the stack trace while the execution is paused at a breakpoint.

Answer (score 1):

Compare

```
var children1 = window[parent1].children;
```

to

```
var numbchildren2 = window[child1].length;
```

I think the second one is missing a ".children" before the length. As Shaed, pointed out, numbchildren2 being incorrectly initialized was the most probable cause of the for loop not running, so you should have been investigating that.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with your syntax of window[elementID] to get an element, but I am pretty sure it does not work. Try using document.getElementById instead.

http://jsfiddle.net/M9jtt/